# Javascript implementation of sha256_crypt

Tags: javascript, cryptography, sha256, sha, crypt

I am looking to create/use a javascript implementation of [passlib.hash.sha256_crypt](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html) where I can specify a salt and password and receive a hash that is in the `$5${salt}${checksum}` format. However all of the javascript implementations I have seen return the output in 64bytes (like what [this site](https://www.symbionts.de/tools/hash/sha256-hash-salt-generator.html) returns).

Is there a javascript implementation that returns the `$5${salt}${checksum}` format? Or at least a way I can convert to this format?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the python directly to JS. Not gurentee to work though, it depends on convertor's quality.

1. Copy python's module:

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
print sha256_crypt.__file__
```

2. Convert python's module to JS

You can use [this site](https://extendsclass.com/python-to-javascript.html), there are lots of free resources online.

I assume they use numpy, so the challenge might be finding a convertor that can handle numpy.

Good luck with your project!